# Why is there a sequence ...?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I have two question. please guide me.

1. for any $ \mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, What are the conditions for the existence of a sequence of $(\mathbf{x}_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ such that
   $  \mathbf{x}_n\to \mathbf{x} $??
2. Let $ \mathbf{0} \in [\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b}]= \{t \mathbf{a}+(1-t) \mathbf{b}: t \in [0,1]\}$ (line segment), for any $ \mathbf{a},\mathbf{b} \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Why is there a sequence  $(\mathbf{b}_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $  \mathbf{b}_n\to \mathbf{b} $, **but** $ \mathbf{0} \notin [\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b}_n]$ $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Thanks

Comment: For question 1, the condition on $x$ is that it must lie in the closure of a set. In other words, it is a limit point of the set and hence there is a sequence converging to $x$.

Comment: the second one is true for  only when $b=0$

Comment: For your first question: for do you know how to solve this for the case that $n = 1$? For your second question, please clarify the following: is the requirement that 
$$
\mathbf 0 \notin [\mathbf a, \mathbf b_n ] \color{red}{\text{ for all $n \in \Bbb N$?}}
$$

Comment: Also, for the second question, do we require that $\mathbf b_n \in [\mathbf a, \mathbf b]$ for all $n \in \Bbb N$?

Comment: As we are not restricted to pick $\mathbf b_k\in[\mathbf a,\mathbf b]$, I'd say that we can achieve $\mathbf 0\notin[\mathbf a,\mathbf b_k]$ iff $\mathbf b=\mathbf 0$ or ($n>1$.and $\mathbf a\ne\mathbf 0$)

Comment: For question 1, it seems you can always pick $\mathbf x_k=\mathbf x$, can't you?

Comment: @BenGrossmann yes. it is requirement that $ 0 \notin [\mathbf{a} , \mathbf{b_n}]$ for any $ n\in \mathbb{N}$. also, It is not needed that $ \mathbf{b_n} \in [\mathbf{a} , \mathbf{b}]$

Comment: @inmath Also, I asked several questions, so I don't know how to interpret the answer "yes."

Comment: @BenGrossmann yes , this is required to hold for all n. i.e.$ 0 \notin [\mathbf{a} , \mathbf{b_n}]$ for any $ n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann For my first question, I can solve it for $n=1$.

Comment: @inmath Great, thank you for clarifying. Since you can solve the problem for $n=1$, could you explain why you find it difficult to answer the question in general? What exactly is the difficult part? Would you be able to answer the question for $n = 2$?

Comment: @BenGrossmann it is difficult to solve **The second question** for $ n>1$ also $ n=1$

Comment: @BenGrossmann **the first question** not difficult for $n=1$. thanks

Comment: @inmath Could you say about more about why the *first* question is difficult for $n > 1$?

Comment: @inmath Ok, that is useful information. It seems as though you are working from a textbook. Does this textbook give a definition of what it means for a sequence in $\Bbb R^n$ to converge?

Comment: @BenGrossmann Not yet. I have not seen it yet. Please introduce me a suitable book.

Comment: @inmath It is hard to recommend a suitable book because I don't know your background, but a classic reference is "Principles of Mathematical Analysis" by Rudin.

Comment: If you have two questions, you need to create two separate posts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $\mathbf v$ denote any non-zero vector that is orthogonal to $\mathbf a$ (i.e. the dot product $\mathbf v \cdot \mathbf a$ is zero). For any $\mathbf p \in \Bbb R^n$, we note that a line connecting $\mathbf a$ to the point $\mathbf p$ goes through zero iff it is parallel to the line from $\mathbf 0$ to $\mathbf a$, i.e. the vector $\mathbf p - \mathbf a$ is a scalar multiple of the vector $\mathbf a$. It follows that if $[\mathbf a, \mathbf p]$ contains $\mathbf 0$, then $\mathbf v \cdot (\mathbf p - \mathbf a) = 0$.

Now, let $\mathbf b_n = \mathbf b + \frac 1n \mathbf v$. I claim that for all $n \in \Bbb N$, $[\mathbf a, \mathbf b_n]$ does not contain the point $\mathbf 0$, and that $\mathbf b_n \to \mathbf b$.

---

For the first problem: ultimately, the nature of your answer depends on your preferred definition of convergence. However, here is an outline of a possible answer:

For any $x \in \Bbb R$, the sequence $x + \frac 1k$ for $k \in \Bbb N$ converges to $x$. Now, let $\mathbf x = (x_1,\dots,x_n)$.  We define
$$
\mathbf x_k = \left(x_1 + \frac 1k , \dots, x_n + \frac 1k\right).
$$
Because each entry of $\mathbf x_k$ converges to the corresponding entry of $\mathbf x$ as $k \to \infty$, we can conclude that $\mathbf x_k \to \mathbf x$.

So, for **every** $\mathbf x \in \Bbb R^n$, there exists a sequence that converges to $\mathbf x$.

Comment: thanks for your answer. what is $ \mathbf{p}$?

Comment: @inmath See my latest edit.

Comment: thanks Ben Grossmann. It was very useful.

Comment: @inmath There are two things that require proving: that $\mathbf b_n \to \mathbf b$, and that $[\mathbf a, \mathbf b_n]$ does not contain $\mathbf 0$ for all $n$. Were you able to proceed with either of these?

Comment: @inmath I don't understand what you mean by a "vector product." Do you understand what I mean by the "dot product"?

Comment: Ben Grossmann, in your answer, if $ \mathbf{v}= \mathbf{0}$, then again $ \mathbf{0} \notin [\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b_n}]$?

Comment: In the  previous comment, $\mathbf{v}$ is Bold.

Comment: @inmath The cross-product $r \times a$ is only defined when $n = 3$.  As long as $n > 1$, we can define $\mathbf v$ as follows: if $\mathbf a = (a_1,\dots,a_n)$ and there is an $i$ for which $a_i = 0$, then take $v$ to be the vector whose $i$th entry is $1$ and whose other entries are $0$. Otherwise, take $\mathbf v = (-a_2,a_1,0,\dots,0)$.

Comment: You took $\mathbf{v}$ non-zero. But if $ \mathbf{v}=0$ and $ \mathbf{b}=0$, then what is answer?

Comment: The answer doesn't change. What changes is that my proof strategy no longer works.  I want to create a sequence such that, for all $n$, $[\mathbf a, \mathbf b_n]$ does not contain the point $0$. If I take $\mathbf v = 0$, then the resulting sequence does not have this property.

Comment: Is the existence of vector $\mathbf{p}$ necessary in the answer? because if $\mathbf{v}$ is orthogonal to $\mathbf{a}$, it is also orthogonal to any scalar multiple of the vector $\mathbf{a}$?  I do not know exactly the role of $\mathbf{p}$. Thanks

Comment: @inmath The vector $\mathbf p$ is a placeholder. The statement "if $[\mathbf a, \mathbf p]$ contains $\mathbf 0$, then $\mathbf v \cdot (\mathbf p - \mathbf a) = 0$" holds for any vector $\mathbf p$. Thus, the statement "if $[\mathbf b_n, \mathbf p]$ contains $\mathbf 0$, then $\mathbf v \cdot (\mathbf b_n - \mathbf a) = 0$" holds for any $n$.

Comment: As a final question: if  $\mathbf{0} \in [\mathbf{b_n}, \mathbf{a}]$ then $\mathbf{v}.(\mathbf{b_n}-\mathbf{a})=\mathbf{0}$ or $  \mathbf{0} \in [\mathbf{b_n}, \mathbf{p}]$???

Comment: @inmath I don't understand your question

Comment: This is true? if $ \mathbf{0} \in [\mathbf{b_n},\mathbf{p}]$ then $ \mathbf{v}.(\mathbf{b_n}-\mathbf{a})=\mathbf{0}$.?

Comment: Yes, as I said in my previous comment, that implication holds. The point, however, is to use the contrapositive: because $\mathbf b_n$ is constructed so that $\mathbf v \cdot (\mathbf b_n - \mathbf a) \neq 0$, it must hold that $\mathbf  0 \notin [\mathbf b_n, \mathbf p]$.

Comment: In the last line of your comment: $$ \mathbf{0} \notin [\mathbf{b_n},\mathbf{a}]$$??

Comment: @inmath Yes, that's what I meant